# How does column order of a clustered Index affect performance

Tags: performance, t-sql, indexing, primary-key, clustered-index

I have a simple mapping table with two foreign key columns  `(CategoryId int, ProductId int)`.  The Primary Key is applied to both columns.

While each Product *can* have more than one category, it is uncommon to ever have more 
than 2.  Categories, on the other hand, commonly have 10k+ products.

**How does the order of the columns in the Primary Key affect performance?**

Common usage of the table is to products based on a category:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM [table] WHERE CategoryId = @catid
```

I understand that if this were a Non-Clustered Index, I would want `CategoryId` first to get best performance from the above query.  Does the same hold true with Clustered Indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the same is true for the clustered index.  The clustering determines the physical order of the rows.  Laying out the table sequentially like this helps I/O on most tables, because the rows and pages can be read by fast sequential I/O instead of random access.

In this case, you could define a clustered index on (CategoryId, ProductId) and a non-clustered index on (ProductId, CategoryId) if you also need to get the categories for a single product.  Note how both indexes have the same keys.  If the mapping table has only 2 columns, the index pages on both indexes will have exactly the same data-- just ordered differently.  The non-clustered index should perform very well here, because SQL Server will not need to do a bookmark lookup to get other data in the row.